# Generate progressive (dense, not like AutoField that skip some) integer in a django model

Tags: django, django-models

Currently, what I do in models.py:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.cod == '':
            self.cod = "CUST%d" % self.id
        super(Customer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and all **seemed** to works well. The thing is that the *id* AutoField actually skips some numbers, I get a scenario like that:

- CUST1
- CUST2
- CUST4
- CUST5

as you can see, there isn't CUST3, the AutoField skipped it.
But for financial purposes, I need that the code has to be progressive and dense.
How I can do to achieve my goal? Thank you

EDIT: I'm using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, as reported also [here](http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/0877x998fr/creating-a-perfect-sequence-column), that is a DBMS related thing that has to do with concurrence and perfomance avoiding gapless sequence.

So I've solved that issue using an aux model 'Progressive' which holds, locks and increments a row.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models, transaction

class Counter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, db_index=True)
    n = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

class Customer(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(Customer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.cod == '':
            with transaction.commit_on_success():
                try:
                    counter = Counter.objects.select_for_update().get(name='Customer')
                except Counter.DoesNotExist:
                    counter = Counter.objects.select_for_update().create(name='Customer')
                self.cod = "CUST%d" % counter.n
                counter.n += 1
                counter.save()
            super(Customer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

note that `select_for_update()` is what locks the row (but pay attention on the DBMS used) until the transaction doesn't terminate.

Hope this helps